# Show that $f\varphi_A$ is contained in $D \cup \partial A$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hey guys i'm having a bit of trouble with this one. I'm hoping that you guys can help me out.

If $D$ is the set of discontinuities of $f:R^n \rightarrow R$, show that the set of discontinuities of $f\varphi_A$ is contained in $D \cup \partial A$

Where $\varphi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$

thanks as always guys

Comment: What's the definition of $f \varphi_A$ ?

Comment: thats all the information they give me... im really not sure

Comment: What book you are reading ? Because although there are some "standard" notation, there are things that each author writes in a different way. Is it Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds?

Comment: I'm reading Advanced Calculus of Several Variables by edwards

Comment: Ahh its the characteristic function... this question is starting to make more sense now.

Comment: Wait, $\varphi_A$ is the characteristic function, not the product by $f$. I'll give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recall some definitions, give some motivation for the exercise and give a hint.

Well, first of all, recall why do we introduce that characteristic function: the integral is easy to define on rectangles, however we want to extend to more sets. So, what we do is construct a function $\varphi_A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $\varphi_A(x)=0$ otherwise. This function indicates if $x$ is or not in $A$.

Now consider a function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is arbitrary. The function $f\varphi_U$ is a function $(f\varphi_U)(x)=f(x)$ for points inside $U$ and and $(f\varphi_U)(x)=0$ for points outside $U$. We are interested in the following: given such $f$, we want to consider some rectangle $A$ such that $U \subset A$ and such that we can extend $f$ to $A$ by this construction with the characteristic function, in other words: the extended function will accord with $f$ on $U$ and be zero on the rest of the rectangle.

We then define the integral over a general set $U$ to be:

$$\int_Uf=\int_A f\varphi_U$$

The RHS is the integral over a rectangle, so this expression will have sense if $f\varphi_U$ is integrable on $A$. For that we need that the set of discontinuities of $f\varphi_U$ has measure $0$. I think this gives you good understanding on what the exercise wants. I think that a good place to start is to find out the set of discontinuities of $\varphi_U$, can you find out where this function is discontinuous?

Comment: Thanks for the hint...I think I understand. I'll ping back with my work if I am having trouble.

Comment: Is this asking if $f$ is essentially differentiable ?

Comment: No, it just asks you to show that the set of discontinuities of $f\varphi_A$ is contained in $D \cup \partial A$. My next hint: show that the set of discontinuities of $\varphi_A$ is simply $\partial A$.

Comment: Oh I see. thanks.. I have class now but this really helped a bunch!

Comment: All this talk about the integral and so on was just to motivate the question. Usually it's better for us to work with something when we know why we are doing it. But the exercise in it's asks something very straightforward: given $D$ the set of discontinuities of $f$, show that the set of discontinuities of $f\varphi_A$ is contained in the union of $D$ and $\partial A$. Use the hint, and see what you get. Good luck!

Comment: I know it was 8 hours ago, but I really want to thank you for your help and not completely giving me the answer. I am pretty happy wit the answer I came up with, given your help.

Comment: @Neo, I'm happy that you've made it. I just want also to give you a sugestion: try a little Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. Both of them treat advanced calculus in a very well explained way. Good luck with your studies.